# For loop error in Firefox and IE but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, runtime-error

I have a weird issue: I have a for loop in JavaScript that works absolutely as expected in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE. In Firefox and IE it adds an undefined item to the array and I have no clue why.

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('itemCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.itemsa = [
        { name: 'testa' },
        { name: 'testb' }
    ];
    $scope.itemsb = [];

    $scope.doSomething = function(IDparam) {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsb.length; i++){
            if ($scope.itemsb[i].name === $scope.itemsa[IDparam].name) { ... }; };
```

According to the developer tools in both browsers the `$scope.itemb` has the length 0 at the for loop start line `for(var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsb.length; i++)` but (for whatever reason) it still starts the for loop (which it shouldn't from what I know) and then in the following line `if ($scope.itemsb[i].name === $scope.itemsa[IDparam].name)` there appears an undefined item for the 0 array position out of nowhere (and then produces an error of course).

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is probably going to be where you call `$scope.doSomething` or where you are adding values to `$scope.itemsb`. Could you please share the code for those two pieces? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! The `$scope.doSomething` gets called in the same controller. It's the only place where the `itemsb array` gets changed: `$scope.addItemb = function(IDparam) {
 if ($scope.doSomething(IDparam)) {
  return false;
 }
 else {
  $scope.$apply($scope.itemb.push($scope.itema[IDparam]));
  return true;
 }; 
};`

Comment: I see that you mention `itema` and `itemb`. Shouldn't those be `itemsa` and `itemsb`?

Comment: A couple of other things. I strongly recommend hopping through this code using Firefox's developer tools. They have a way to set breakpoints in your code. I would set it at the loop and step up the call stack until you find why `$scope.itemsb` is getting populated.

Comment: Argh, sorry, you are right. I made these mistakes while adjusting the code for here. It is correct in the actual code (if not, it wouldn't work in Chrome just fine).

Comment: I made breakpoints on both lines and I tried to figure out where and why it gets populated but I have no clue at all. :(

Comment: Okay, I could figure out something: The `$scope.doSomething` gets called again after the I push the `$scope.itemsa[IDparam]));` in the array. And after this push the array `$scope.itemsb` has the undefined element. So what's going wrong is actually the push. And the push is going wrong because the `$scope.itemsa`for whatever reason is `undefined` when it's about to be pushed.

Comment: One small step for man kind, one giant leap for `$scope.doSomething`!

Comment: Hahahaha, thank you so much for your help and pushing me to intensify my investigation. I finally found the issue and of course: I was looking in the wrong place. :-/ The issue was the `IDparam`which I received out of `ui.draggable[0].attributes[2].value` but obviously the order of the attributes change in IE and FF (further research necessary), which means I didn't get a proper ID but a whole pile of crap instead in this param. ;-( Thanks again, I will check now how to get the ID cross-browser. :)

Comment: Yep, that will do it. No worries. Glad you figured it out. Keep up the good work and happy coding!